# Laravel 5.1 Get Input Value

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I am creating an Xml like this:

```
private function setTitle()
{
    $rC        = $this->data->rC;
    $cTimes    = array();
    $i         = 0;

    foreach ($rC as $rCKey => $rCValue)
    {
        $cTimes[] = $rCValue->input_c_start;
    }

    foreach ($rC as $rCKey => $rCValue)
    {
        $this->title = $this->titleSetTitles->addChild('title');
        $this->title->addAttribute('chapters', $cTimes[$i]);
        $i++;
    }

}
```

the output is something like this:

```
  <title chapters="00:01">
    ...
  </title>
  <title chapters="00:02">
    ...
  </title>
```

My question is now how to add in each loop the chapter times so that it looks like this:

```
  <title chapters="00:01">
    ...
  </title>
  <title chapters="00:01; 00:02">
    ...
  </title>
  <title chapters="00:01; 00:02; 00:03">
    ...
  </title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have another variable outside the foreach loop which gets data appended on each iteration.

```
private function setTitle()
{
    $rC        = $this->data->rC;
    $cTimes    = array();
    $i         = 0;
    $chapters  = "";

    foreach ($rC as $rCKey => $rCValue)
    {
        $cTimes[] = $rCValue->input_c_start;
    }

    foreach ($rC as $rCKey => $rCValue)
    {
        $chapters .= $cTimes[$i]."; ";
        $this->title = $this->titleSetTitles->addChild('title');
        $this->title->addAttribute('chapters', substr($chapters, 0, -2));
        $i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: works, but I get a whitespace at the end how would you make a conditions which prevents that :`chapters="00:00:00; 00:10:00; ">`

Comment: @JohnDoe2 Remove last 2 chars with substr see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Have a extra variable and use like this:-

```
private function setTitle(){
    $rC        = $this->data->rC;
    $cTimes    = array();
    $i         = 0;

    foreach ($rC as $rCKey => $rCValue){
        $cTimes[] = $rCValue->input_c_start;
    }
    $ncTime = [];
    foreach ($rC as $rCKey => $rCValue){
        $ncTime[] = $cTimes[$i];
        $this->title = $this->titleSetTitles->addChild('title');
        $this->title->addAttribute('chapters', implode(";", $ncTime));
        $i++;
     }
}
```